# Unable to grant access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I bought an apple developer account and I'm trying to add a user as admin and grant access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. But the checkbox is disabled I'm unable to tick it.

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you have created Apple Developer account as **Individual**.

To Add other user as Admin with (Certificate, Identifiers & Profiles) access you just need to change your Apple Developer account from **Individual** to **Company / Organisation** and then you will be able to grant above access to your added users.

Comment: My clients add me as an admin in their apple developer account to upload the app in their account. Till few months back I ask them to invite in 1.appstoreconnect.apple.com and 2.developer.apple.com member. 2.I get access to developer.apple.com to create certificates. 1.I get access to appstoreconnect.apple.com to upload/release builds. It seems option 2 isn't available now. How to some my problem without accessing the account holder's account?

Comment: and do I have to pay $299 to do this?

Comment: In my case I have admin access to the Apple Developer account after our client has changed the account type to "Company/Organisation" from "Individual". But cannot access the "Certificate, Identifiers and profiles". Then "account holder" has deleted my user account and resend invitation including access to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles". After accepting new invitation I got access to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

Comment: @TejaK you only have to continue paying the standard $99/year to be part of the apple developer program.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:**

- You need to enrol on the  Apple developer program as an **organization**, and to do this,
- you need to be **legally registered** as an organized, because
- you need your **"DUNS" number**.

### Organization account required

Your apple developer account must be an organization to have other developers added via App Store Connect to create their provisioning profiles. It doesn't cost more, it just requires more information / setup.

As per the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/):

> Note: If you’re enrolled as an **individual** and add users in App Store Connect, users receive access only to your content in App Store Connect and are **not considered part of your team in the Apple Developer Program**.

and

> Management of users and roles is done in App Store Connect.

Therefore, you have to be an organization. This does not cost anything extra.

As everyone else, I found [Kuldeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56180872/7365866) useful, but wanted more official documentation.

Although another apple page under "Enrolling in the Apple Developer Program as an **individual**" says:

> If you're an individual or sole proprietor/single-person business, follow these steps to enroll

### Company registration required

I called the Apple support team, and the mentioned that they do migrations to Organization accounts for sole proprieters all the time.

You can "try" to find your organization on the [DUNS lookup page](https://developer.apple.com/enroll/duns-lookup/#!/search) with valid details. If it doesn't succeed in finding it, it can submit for you.

However, a few days after I submitted the form, I was **not** given a DUNS number. Instead, I got a reply saying no business exists for this organization. This concludes that you **need a business registration**. You can see the email at [Applying for DUNS Number: 'Apple Tracking Number' and 'Purpose'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70434630/7365866).

After being on the phone with Apple support, I gave them some constructive feedback: we should have a "team" account, not just "Individual" and "Organization".

Comment: Just to reinforce that an Individual type Apple Developer Account DOES NOT have access to grant 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' to another user. The tick box simply does not exist. I've verified this directly with Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here,

Client add me as as Admin in Appstore, but they missed to give access for

**Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**

[image]

Once they give Admin access then need to give access for
**Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**

Or else they delete your account and add it again, that time give access for all.

Answer (score -2):

The details about all the access and user roles are explained at https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29910821)