# cannot install iOS app: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Tags: iphone, xcode, expo, provisioning-profile, xcode12

I'm trying to build and install an iOS app to my iPhone after ejecting to bare workflow from an expo managed project.

I'm getting "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

- I ran `expo eject`
- I attached my iPhone 12 to the Mac mini M1 via USB and trusted it
- I opened `myproject.xcworkspace` with Xcode 12.5
- The signing certificate and provisioning profile were generated by expo
- I cannot use "Automatically manage signing" because the account holder of the app is of type individual (not business), which means [my apple developer account does not have access to certificates, identifiers and profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001333/unable-to-grant-access-to-certificates-identifiers-profiles) (even though I am an Admin in the account holder's team).
- So I downloaded the certificate and provisioning profile from expo and set it manually in Xcode
- I also imported the private key of the signing cert to my keychain
- Xcode is happy and builds, the error appears at the very end after copying the app to the phone
- Then I also registered my device (iPhone) in the apple developer account of the account holder

Don't know what else I could do. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Error:

```
Unable to install "myproject"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
--
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008015)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012c2b5e98 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012c2f1898 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010067f644 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012c2f15e4 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1316
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012c1b3d40 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 2928
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001007a8814 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001007aa238 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 680
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000196dc60f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000196dc7e90 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000196dcf678 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 620
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000196dd0274 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 404
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000196ddab44 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 764
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000196f72ff8 _pthread_wqthread + 276
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000196f71d30 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.3.1 (Build 20E241)
Xcode 12.5 (18205) (Build 12E262)
Timestamp: 2021-05-21T17:24:28+02:00
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @greenskin No, I gave up with individual accounts, I just wasted weeks. I am now using business accounts and automatic signing. This also allows giving access to certificates and provisioning profiles for non-account-holders.